# Нужно попасть на чужой сайт, доменное имя которого просрочено

Tags: dns

Мы с товарищем искали почту одной организации. Пришли к выводу, что единственный способ связи с организацией - форма связи на их сайте. (Оттуда же письма на их почту должны приходить автоматически?)

Оплата доменного имени сайта с той формой, пока мы думали - оказалась просрочена. Теперь мы пытаемся понять, вот если мы выкупим доменное имя, сможем ли мы из каких-то архивов выковырять чужой сайт и заставить работать на нас, чтобы связаться?

Мы не разбираемся в IT.

Уже пробовали просить почту в техподдержке, но нас перенаправили на торги. Никто ничего не знает.

Comment: _если мы выкупим доменное имя, сможем ли мы из каких-то архивов выковырять чужой сайт_ - нет.

Comment: Спасибо, но почему? Есть ведь в гугле много возмущений "Почему по имени моего домена открывается другой сайт?" - стало быть, как-то это может произойти.

Comment: Для «восстановления» доменного имени достаточно просто прописать его в файл hosts на своём компьютере. А вот «из каких-то архивов выковырять чужой сайт» вам никто не даст

Comment: @andreymal да ладно вам, вон хакеры через DevTool сайты ломают, а тут всего то "скачать" чужой сайт.

Answer (score 2):

Доменное имя - это только имя, которому соответствует конкретный IP адрес. И этот адрес означает конкретный компютер (сервер, или множество конкретных серверов).

Значит, покупкой вы получите только имя, и в зависимости от типа покупки может быть вместе с IP адресом сервера продавца.

Но это будет **совершенно другой IP адрес и другой компютер** - пока вы его не покупите у того же продавца, как ваш предшественник. Но и в этом случае *не получите то, что вы хотите* - пулучите пустое место на его сервере, ни каких дат вашего предшественника.

Comment: Если сервер каким-то чудом ещё существует, то можно попытаться прописать его IP-адрес в свежекупленный домен

Answer (score 2):

Как я понимаю Вам необходима помощь, не уверен что именно это Вам поможет но высока вероятность что может помочь, поэтому опубликую этот способ.

Для примера я зайду на сайт документации игрового движка https://www.pygame.org/ — сайт заблокирован так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зайду на сайт https://web.archive.org/ и введу имя сайта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее нажму <kbd>Enter</kbd> и увижу календарь архива, я могу переходить по датам и находить нужную версию сайта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перебрав несколько дат я попадаю на сайт и вверху вижу узкой полоской календарь для возможности дальнейшего перемещения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Конечно, это не гарантирует что вы сможете отправить письмо, но возможно там будет контактная информация для связи или другие полезные данные.*

Надеюсь, мой ответ, поможет решить Вашу задачу, если поможет, то пожалуйста отметьте мой ответ зеленой галочкой, возможно, этот ответ кому-то еще сможет помочь.